# Call UserForm on Save

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I go about calling a userform in VBA when user clicks on the Save button in MS Word?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to do that: You can either override the built-in `FileSave` and `FileSaveAs` commands, or you can create an event handler for the application's `DocumentBeforeSave` event (which is a little more work to do).

Overriding the built-in commands can be accomplished by adding the following code to a VBA module (adjust the type of the user form to be displayed accordingly):

```
' override File -> Save
Public Sub FileSave()

    CustomSave
    ' call ActiveDocument.Save to actually save the document

End Sub

' override File -> Save As...
Public Sub FileSaveAs()

    CustomSave
    ' call ActiveDocument.SaveAs to actually save the document

End Sub

Sub CustomSave()

    Dim frm As New frmCustomSave
    frm.Show

End Sub
```

The second option can be implemented by placing the following code under *Microsoft Word Objects* -> *ThisDocument* in the VBA editor:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents wdApp As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_New()
    Set wdApp = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set wdApp = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub wdApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim frm As New frmCustomSave
    frm.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Intercepting events like Save and Print](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm) for an example that should help.